# Moto g4 plus can't be unlocked

Tags: bootloader, motorola-moto-g, bootloader-lock, motorola-moto-g-4g-plus

When I go to unlock my moto g4 plus, I get a message that my computer cannot be unlocked. This is the getvar all result

```
(bootloader) version: 0.5
(bootloader) version-bootloader: moto-msm8952-B1.07
(bootloader) product: athene_16mp
(bootloader) board: athene_16mp
(bootloader) secure: yes
(bootloader) hwrev: P2A
(bootloader) radio: 1
(bootloader) storage-type: emmc
(bootloader) emmc: 64GB SAMSUNG RC14MB RV=08 PV=07 FV=0000000000000007
(bootloader) ram: 4GB SAMSUNG LP3 DIE=8Gb M5=01 M6=05 M7=00 M8=5F
(bootloader) cpu: MSM8952
(bootloader) serialno: ZY223D4PT9
(bootloader) cid: 0x0032
(bootloader) channelid: 0x8d
(bootloader) uid: (ommited)
(bootloader) securestate: oem_locked
(bootloader) iswarrantyvoid: no
(bootloader) max-download-size: 536870912
(bootloader) reason: Reboot mode set to fastboot
(bootloader) imei: (ommited)
(bootloader) meid: 
(bootloader) date: 09-11-2016
(bootloader) sku: XT1644
(bootloader) battid: SNN5970A
(bootloader) iccid: 
(bootloader) cust_md5: 
(bootloader) max-sparse-size: 268435456
(bootloader) current-time: "Mon Dec 26 17: 6:59 UTC 2016"
(bootloader) ro.build.fingerprint[0]: motorola/athene_f/athene_f:7.0/NPJ
(bootloader) ro.build.fingerprint[1]: S25.93-14.7-5/6:user/release-keys
(bootloader) ro.build.version.full[0]: Blur_Version.25.251.6.athene.reta
(bootloader) ro.build.version.full[1]: il.en.US
(bootloader) ro.build.version.qcom: LA.BR.1.3.6-01710-8976.0
(bootloader) version-baseband[0]: M8952_70030.25.03.64.01R ATHENE_RETUSA
(bootloader) version-baseband[1]: _CUST
(bootloader) kernel.version[0]: Linux version 3.10.84-g2ccb7a8 (hudsoncm
(bootloader) kernel.version[1]: @ilclbld86) (gcc version 4.8 (GCC) ) #1 
(bootloader) kernel.version[2]: SMP PREEMPT Sat Feb 3 22:42:15 CST 2018
(bootloader) sbl1.git: git=MBM-NG-VB1.07-0-g57d1343
(bootloader) rpm.git: git=a970ead
(bootloader) tz.git: git=69dd24b-dirty
(bootloader) hyp.git: git=69dd24b-dirty
(bootloader) keymaster.git: git=69dd24b-dirty
(bootloader) cmnlib.git: git=69dd24b-dirty
(bootloader) aboot.git: git=MBM-NG-VB1.07-0-gf9b89ba
(bootloader) qe: qe 0/0
(bootloader) frp-state: no protection (144)
(bootloader) ro.carrier: retus
all: listed above
finished. total time: 0.076s
```

The cid is listed as valid on their post, and others can unlock their moto g4 pluses

Comment: Have you enabled your bootloader to be unlocked from the developer menu in settings?

Comment: @Sonickyle27 yes i have and also enabled usb debugging

Comment: So what else have you done? Obtained the unlock code at Moto's site? Tried to unlock with that code, and it failed? What command did you issue, and what error (exactly) was shown?

Comment: I tried to get the unlock code, but it told me that it didn't qualify for it